# Remove column from TB Mega Menu

Tags: navigation

I have a site menu with this structure on TB MegaMenu:

```
  Level 1
     **Level 2a heading**|**Level 2b heading**|**Level 2c heading**
             item         item                 item
```

How can I remove/delete column 2b from the menu

**note: I have already removed level 2b from the admin menu but it's still showing the level 2b heading and a blank space beneath it. I want the whole column to be removed.**

Comment: Maybe an example of what you're seeing from the Browser DOM or the Drupal UI to give everyone greater context.